# Couldn't read row 1, col 1 from CursorWindow?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm just trying to pull all of the categories from my Database:

```
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "WishListDB.DB";
private static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items_table";
private static final String COLUMN_INDEX = "item_index";
private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "item_title";

private static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "item_category";

private static final String COLUMN_VENDOR = "item_vendor";
private static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "item_price";
private static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "item_image";
```

So my overall goal is to get all the categories, and store them in an ArrayList too then pass into a spinner in my Activity. Here is where I call for the data:

```
    db_manager = new databaseManager(this, null, null, 1); 
    int index_value = (int) db_manager.Get_Length_of_DB();
    for (int i = 0; i <= index_value; i++)
    {

        category_List = db_manager.get_all_Categories();
    }
    ArrayAdapter categories_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_List);
    cat_spinner.setAdapter(categories_adapter);
```

And here is my "get_all_categories" method

```
public ArrayList<String> get_all_Categories()
{

    String get_Cats_Query = "SELECT item_category from " + TABLE_ITEMS;
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(get_Cats_Query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> cats_from_db = new ArrayList<String>() {};
    if(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            cats_from_db.add(cursor.getString(i));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return cats_from_db;

}
```

and here's the error:

```
 Failed to read row 1, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 1 columns.     

 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col 1 from 
 CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before 
 accessing data from it.
```

I'm not really that great with databases so I'm really struggling with this, I've successfully added to the database but can't figure out how to get the data out. If anyone can help It would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: obviously `Cursor.getString(int)` takes field (column) number not row number as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is **get_all_Categories** you are trying to get wrong column index try below code

```
public ArrayList<String> get_all_Categories()
{

    String get_Cats_Query = "SELECT item_category from " + TABLE_ITEMS;
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(get_Cats_Query, null);

    ArrayList<String> cats_from_db = new ArrayList<String>() {};
    if( cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            cats_from_db.add(cursor.getString(0));
         }
         while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return cats_from_db;

}
```

Also your code  totally unnecessary looping to get data from db which actually overriding your arraylist not understand what you trying to do

Comment: Yeah that loop was coded when I was quite tired haha sorted that now. Thanks so much for your answer you're an actual life saver. Only issue I'm having now is that it's saving both the category and the title into the ArrayList? Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: create arraylist of custom object check this you will get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377312/create-new-object-in-arraylist-with-attributes

Comment: So I should make a custom object list, then call the data to fill it like: ArrayList<custom> ListName.add(get_all_categories(), get_all_vendors(), method3()); ? wouldn't this still be pulling the same data tho, so still pulling the title where the category is supposed to be?

Comment: if your data related to same table only different column then create class with needed object then change your databse query and function to get data and set that data to class attribute and add that class in ArrayList